# Docker deployment on Elastic Beanstalk not gathering NGINX logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

According to [Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker Configuration docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html), I should be able to use mount points to get NGINX logs in the location where Elastic Beanstalk expects them.

> Volumes from the container instance to mount and the location on the container file system at which to mount them. Mount volumes containing application content so your container can read the data you upload in your source bundle, as well as log volumes for writing log data to a location where Elastic Beanstalk can gather it.
>
> Elastic Beanstalk creates log volumes on the container instance, one for each container, at /var/log/containers/containername. These volumes are named awseb-logs-containername and should be mounted to the location within the container file structure where logs are written.
>
> For example, the following mount point maps the nginx log location in the container to the Elastic Beanstalk–generated volume for the nginx-proxy container.

```
{
  "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
  "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

I have done this for two NGINX containers in my app, but EB doesn't deliver the NGINX logs when I request logs.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "gs-api-nginx-versioning",
      "image": "829481521991.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/gs-api-nginx-versioning:latest",
      "memory": 128,
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-gs-api-nginx-versioning",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 443,
          "containerPort": 443
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "gs-api-v1-nginx:v1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "gs-api-v1-nginx",
      "image": "829481521991.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/gs-api-v1-nginx:latest",
      "memory": 128,
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-gs-api-v1-nginx",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "gs-api-v1-atlas-vms:atlas-vms",
        "gs-api-v1-auth:auth",
        "gs-api-v1-clean-zip:clean-zip",
        "gs-api-v1-data-alerts:data-alerts",
        "gs-api-v1-proc-events:proc-events",
        "gs-api-v1-sites:sites"
      ]
    },
    <additional container configs>
  ]
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here that's causing the logs not to be gathered?

Comment: In order to isolate the problem, let's first verify that the logs are written by the container: `ssh` to the Beanstalk EC2 instance and run `docker exec -it <container_id> bash`, then do `ls -l /var/log/nginx`. If you can see the logs there, verify you can see the files on the host: run `ls -l /var/log/containers/<container_name>` and make sure logs are getting written there. You can run `tail -f` on the files there and make sure you see new lines when browsing the Beanstalk URL.

Comment: @JohananLiebermann I have similar problem, I can see mine in `/var/log/containers/<container_name>` but I cannot see them on cloudwatch, but I do so all the ones from the directory `/var/log/ecs` - any ideas? (Also shows fine when request logs from EBS)

Comment: @MattTheNinja - no idea about the specific problem you're seeing, but I would take a look at the following: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.cw.html. As long as you're using an official Beanstalk AMI, the official AWS docs should apply and things should work out of the box.

Comment: @JohananLiebermann i've been over and over this. Question is here https://serverfault.com/questions/871653/amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk-ebs-logs-to-cloudwatch-multi-docker-env I assume it auto creates the cloudwatch log group if it see the directory in `/var/log` or do you have to define additional log folders to send to cloudwatch?

Comment: @MattTheNinja - looks like you need to configure the CloudWatch Logs agent to monitor the files at `/var/log/containers`. See my answer on your post for an explanation and some official references.